# How do i use table data from my sqlite3 database as a python variable

Tags: python, database, sqlite

My code so far

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('databaserm/database')      
curs = conn.cursor()         
curs.execute('SELECT * FROM saves')     
lvl = curs.fetchone()    
conn.close()
```

ok maybes its the code i used to add the data to the db

i've tried this

```
cn = sqlite3.connect(/databaserm/database")
curs = cn.cursor()
curs.execute('DROP TABLE saves')
curs.execute('CREATE TABLE saves (lvl)')
#curs.execute('INSERT INTO saves VALUES (null, ?)', lvl)

query = """INSERT INTO saves (lvl)
                VALUES (?)"""
data =  [lvl]

curs.execute(query, data)

cn.commit
cn.close()
```

and this

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/databaserm/database')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('INSERT INTO saves VALUES(null, ?,)', (lvl,))
conn.commit
```

Comment: you're changing your question on-the-fly, and your formatting is unintelligible. please be respectful enough to spend 2 minutes on formulating a well-defined quesion that's properly formatted

Comment: i'm very sorry, i'm tired and really should be getting to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `select` and then `fetchone` will return a tuple. What else do you need?

Here's an example:

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite

con = sqlite.connect(':memory:')
cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
    create table names (id integer primary key,
                        name varchar(50), email varchar(50))''')

cursor.execute('''
    insert into names values (null, "John Doe", "jdoe@jdoe.zz")''')
cursor.execute('''
    insert into names values (null, "Mary Sue", "msue@msue.yy")''')

name = """Lu'k'e d"fdf" Sma"""
email = "use@force.net"

cursor.execute(
    '''insert into names values (null, ?, ?)''',
    (name, email))

cursor.execute('select * from names')

for c in cursor:
    print c
```

Uses iteration over `cursor` (an alternative way to get result). Prints:

```
(1, u'John Doe', u'jdoe@jdoe.zz')
(2, u'Mary Sue', u'msue@msue.yy')
(3, u'Lu\'k\'e d"fdf" Sma', u'use@force.net')
```

Using `fetchone` instead of iteration:

```
print cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
```

Prints:

```
(1, u'John Doe', u'jdoe@jdoe.zz')
```